# login failed to remote host - prompt does not match at /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.10.0/Net/Appliance/Session/Transport.pm line 78

Tags: perl, network-programming

I keep getting the following error on some devices, some the exact same IOS and version.

We had an issue when accessing the device : 10.XX.XX.XX
10.XX.XX.XX The reported error was : login failed to remote host - prompt does not match at /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.10.0/Net/Appliance/Session/Transport.pm line 78.

Does anyone have experience with this package?  Also, when a device is down I still get a ok resonse? How would I say ping the device first?

Thanks

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use Net::Appliance::Session;

$file = '1list';
open (FH, "< $file") or die "Can't open $file for read: $!";
my @ios_list = <FH>;
close FH or die "Cannot close $file: $!";

chomp(@ios_list);

my $ios_username = 'xxxx';
my $ios_password = 'xxxx';

DEVICE:
for my $ios_device_ip ( @ios_list ) {

        my @version_info;

        my $proto = shift;
        if (($proto == 43)||($proto == 44)){
                $tran = "SSH";
                $app="/usr/local/bin/ssh";
        }else{
                $tran = "Telnet";
                $app="/bin/telnet";
        }

        my $session_obj = Net::Appliance::Session->new(
                host => $ios_device_ip,
                transport => $tran,
                personality => 'ios',
        );

#interace

        eval {
                 # try to login to the ios device, ignoring host check
                $session_obj->connect(
                username => $ios_username,
                password => $ios_password,
                #SHKC => 0
        );

        # get our running config
        $session_obj->begin_privileged;
        $session_obj->cmd('conf t');
        $session_obj->cmd('aaa authorization config-commands');
        $session_obj->cmd('exit');
        $session_obj->end_privileged;
        $session_obj->cmd('write memory');
        # close down our session
        $session_obj->close;
        };

#error check
        if ($@) {

     if ( UNIVERSAL::isa($@, 'Net::Appliance::Session::Exception') ) {

         # fault description from Net::Appliance::Session
         print "We had an error during our Telnet/SSH session to device  : $ios_devi
ce_ip \n";
         print $@->message . " \n";

         # message from Net::Telnet
         print "Net::Telnet message : " . $@->errmsg . "\n";

         # last line of output from your appliance
         print "Last line of output from device : " . $@->lastline . "\n\n";

     }
     elsif (UNIVERSAL::isa($@, 'Net::Appliance::Session::Error') ) {

         # fault description from Net::Appliance::Session
         print "We had an issue during program execution to device : $ios_device_ip
\n";
#         print $@->message . " \n";

     }
     else {

         # we had some other error that wasn't a deliberately created exception
         print "We had an issue when accessing the device : $ios_device_ip \n";
         print "$ios_device_ip The reported error was : $@ \n";
     }

     next DEVICE;
 }

print @version_info;
print "$ios_device_ip ok \n";
#end
}
```

Comment: Have you tried connecting manually (i.e. without `Net::Appliance::Session`) to a device that works and to one that gives the error to see what is different? It seems like `Net::Appliance::Session` is expecting a different prompt than what is actually appearing.

Comment: That is the odd thing, all devices give the same prompt once logged in.  Some devices are the exact same model, ios version and almost the same config.  Yet one works fine, one does not.

Comment: Well something is clearly different. Perhaps it's a matter of timing, and one device takes longer to boot up than another; it could also be that the error message is incorrect and `Net::Appliance::Session` is unable to connect for some other reason, like invalid credentials. I would pick two devices of the same model and ios version, one that works and one that doesn't, [turn on diagnostics](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::Appliance::Session#DIAGNOSTICS), try to connect to each, log the results, and compare. If possible, make the configurations match first.

Comment: I think I found the problem.  Seems to be a issue with hostnames?  For example switch(a939393).  If I remove (a939393), no problem.

Comment: Is `switch(a939393)` really your hostname? If so, it's invalid, because [hostnames can only contain ASCII a-z, 0-9, and hyphens](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hostname#Restrictions_on_valid_host_names).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The hostnames of the devices I failed to connect to looked like:

```
switch(a939393)
```

These hostnames were invalid because [valid hostnames](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hostname#Restrictions_on_valid_host_names) can only contain ASCII a-z, A-Z, 0-9, and hyphens‌​. This was the source of the issue.

Comment: Just FYI, comments on Stack Overflow are not intended to be permanent, and are often deleted. Your original answer, by itself, didn't explain exactly what was wrong with your hostnames, so future visitors with the same problem wouldn't know how you fixed your issue. I edited my last comment into your answer in case the comments get deleted.